# Java application not displaying database exactly the way it is

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, jtable

I have this Java application when I run it, it is supposed to pick values from a table in MySQL database. Although, when it runs, it does not pick the correct values from the table as is on the database for certain columns. This is how the table looks like:

---

```
select SLOT_ID, ZONE_LOCATION, CAR_LICENSE, ENTRY_TIME, EXIT_TIME from TBL_ZONE_STATUS;

+---------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| SLOT_ID | ZONE_LOCATION | CAR_LICENSE | ENTRY_TIME | EXIT_TIME |
+---------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| TFSCPA2 | Taifa Rd      | KCB001A     | 08:02:50   | 16:30:22  |
| TFSCPA4 | Taifa Rd      | KXL092A     | 11:10:01   | 20:08:24  |
| TFSCPA1 | Taifa Rd      | KYG099Z     | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00  |
| TFSCPA3 | Taifa Rd      | KYG101B     | 10:30:22   | 17:02:00  |
+---------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

This is the description of the same table:

```
mysql> describe TBL_ZONE_STATUS;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SLOT_ID       | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ZONE_NUMBER   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ZONE_NAME     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ZONE_LOCATION | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PARKING_TYPE  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CAR_LICENSE   | varchar(15)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ENTRY_TIME    | time         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EXIT_TIME     | time         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When the application runs the same query and displays it in a TableModel, this is what it shows:

[image]

Bear with me. I am not able to post the image here directly because of my rep but, as you can see on the image at the entry and exit time column, it shows dates rather. Keep in mind that, before, this column's data type was *datetime* which I then changed to *time* only. MySQL automatically removed the dates after that change but the application did not. Even before the change, the application did not show the time values. It only showed the dates. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @Abhik Chakraborty. I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Try to use  ResultSet.getTimestamp(String columnLabel).

Comment: @newuserua_ext am not sure of where to apply that.

Comment: In this code where you get that column. But i think there is some logical mistake. For example if somebody enter at 08:00(entry_time) and exit after 24 hours and 1 minute later like 08:01(exit_time) so how do you suppose calculate time difference between enter and exit time. i think ENTRY_TIME and EXIT_TIME should contain DATE type. Maybe after all code will be work fine without any changes ;)

Comment: I have already considered that possibility.  My only problem is for the application to show me exactly how the database is... Like running the simple query "select * from TBL_ZONE_STATUS".  I don't think my code affects the output in any way but let me try posting it.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that ;

> Keep in mind that, before, this column's data type was datetime which I then changed to time only

You should change also your code. Find  and change your enrty_time and exit_time line with **ResultSet.getTime(String columnLabel)** where you read data from TBL_ZONE_STATUS